# Por que uma div não fica ao lado da outra?

Tags: html, css

Tenho duas `div`s seguidas, sendo que uma tem um `width` de `100px` e a outra `200px`. Somando a largura das duas (300px) fica bem abaixo da largura do *viewport* da tela (numa tela desktop, por exemplo), mas a segunda aparece abaixo da primeira:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#lateral{
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
}

#main{
   width: 200px;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="lateral">
   lateral
</div>
<div id="main">
   main
</div>
```

Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

Uma `div` sempre fica abaixo da outra independentemente da largura ou é preciso sempre usar `float` para que uma fique ao lado da outra? A `div` sempre força uma "quebra de linha" no layout? Por quê isso se a largura das duas somadas não excedem a largura da tela?

Se eu usar `float: left` resolveria, mas não queria usar `float` porque caso eu queira centralizar as duas uma ao lado da outra o `float` vai impedir isso.

Não tenho conhecimentos avançados em CSS, e algumas situações me parecem confusas de entender, como esta, por exemplo.

Comment: para isso ou você usar bootstrap usando as classes condener row col-xs-6, ou no seu arquivo css coloca possição absoluta e outras coisas n sei falar direito

Comment: Obrigado, mas é que eu não uso Bootstrap neste caso e nem pretendo usar. :D

Comment: Isso eh devido ao box model da div, ela eh um elemento do tipo bloco, o mesmo acontece com a tag P ou H1 por exemplo. Se vc tiver duas tag P vai ficar uma em cada linha, mesmo que tenha só um caractere. Eh mais uma questão do html que do CSS, apesar que com CSS vc muda essa característica default do elemento, seja com float, display inline, Flex ou grid por exemplo

Comment: @hugocsl Eu sei, mas mesmo setando um width pequeno?

Comment: Eu to na casa da minha noiva e ela esta aqui falando pra eu parar de "jogar" hahaha, mas se não tiver uma resposta mais completa ate amanha eu posto algo a respeito com uns exemplos

Comment: Para complementar a resposta do Andrew e o comentário do Hugo: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: @hugocsl Isso se chama "vício".. rss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uma div sempre fica abaixo da outra independentemente da largura?

**Por default, sim! Isso se deve ao fato do display padrão da div ser block. O bloco renderiza uma linha inteira, como o amigo @hugocsl comentou.**

> É preciso sempre usar float para que uma fique ao lado da outra?

**É uma das formas. Existem "n" formas de se fazer isso, por exemplo, flex box.**

Pra exemplificar com flex, por exemplo:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="width: 200px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços.

Comment: Obg pela resposta, bem útil. Mas o problema do flexbox é que caso eu diminua a tela a segunda div não cai pra baixo. Ou cai?

Comment: Cai sim. Basta você adicionar a propriedade `flex-wrap: wrap;` a classe flex container.

Comment: Ficou legal! Valeu pela ajuda!